# Issue in the firestore while running through cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have implemented my python code as per https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-gcs-bq-streaming-functions-python/blob/master/functions/streaming/main.py

Just instead of storage trigger, I am using a pubsub trigger through cloud scheduler and loading the files present in a bucket.

But while running the function I am getting below error.

**raise valueerror("a document must have an even number of path elements")**

I am using firestore version 1.8.1 in requirements file.

Can someone please suggest me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you're trying to use a Firestore collection as a document. Check that all your Firestore document paths are correct.

```
# Odd number of path elements means it's a collection, not a doc
doc_ref_error = db.document('collection/document/subcollection')
# Fixed
doc_ref = db.document('collection/document/subcollection/subdocument')
```